# Plot data being misdisplayed in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Why are my datapoints being displayed like this when new data is being dumped via stream into "twitter-out"? Seems like it has to do with the animation, because when I rerun the file without streaming in new data it plots just fine.

[image]

```
    style.use('ggplot')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

def animate(self):

    pullData = open("twitter-out.txt", "r").read()
    lines = pullData.split('\n')

    xar = []
    yar = []

    x = 0
    y = 0

    for l in lines[:]:
        x += 1
        if "['pos']" in l:
            y += 1
        elif "['neg']" in l:
            y -= 1

        xar.append(x)
        yar.append(y)

    ax1.plot(xar, yar,color='r')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Number of Tweets')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Sentiment')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fix 1:**

The main fix for this is very easy : just add `ax1.cla()` before you call `ax1.plot()`

**Explanation :**

The reason for what you see is that the animation draws a new plot each time the `animate` function is called and stack it above all the previous ones. 
So the figure you have attached in your question is actualy a superposition of the dozen figures that were drawn from the `animate` calls. 
To solve that you just have to clear the previous plots that were contained in your axes with the clear axes command `ax.cla()`.

**Fix 2:**

The reason for the horizontal bars to be there at all is because your `dataPulled` string always ends with a new line that turns in an empty string at the end of your list `line`.
See that example:

```
>>> 'a\nb\n'.split('\n')
['a', 'b', '']
```

So you have to cut that last one out in your `for` loop:

```
for l in lines[:-1]:
```